# Can't find pre-released versions of ML-Agents in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, reinforcement-learning, ml-agent

I am trying to use pre-released versions of packages on Unity.
I followed some tutorials and guides, and from my understanding, I should check the "Enable pre-release packages" Check-box as I did here:

[image: Here]

But still, when I go to the package manager, I don't see any newer version.

[image: Here is what I see after checking the check-box]

How do I fix it? I want to use the OnActionReceived(ActionBuffers actions) function, and on my current version, I cant use it.

I'm using the Unity version 2021.1.19f1

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's written in the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ml-agents@2.1/manual/index.html):

> Advanced Installation
>
> With the changes to Unity Package Manager in 2021, experimental packages will not show up in the package list and have to be installed manually. There are two recommended ways to install the package manually:
>
> ...

Once you've done that you can use pre-release:

[image]